# WP redirect to custom login page if a user is not logged in

Tags: templates

I want to login a user before he watches content of our site but I am always in a redirect loop, I don't know why. but I searched all the google and stackoverflow but could not find it's solution. Please take a look at my codes

```
function redirect_login_page() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/account/') );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_login_page' );
```

I also tried this

```
function redirect_login_page() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_redirect( 'https://playground.com/account/' );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_login_page' );
```

Nothing of the upper works perfect.I always get this `....redirected you too many times.`

But as per wp_redirect there might be any problem. I also used this `wp_redirect( home_url('/account/'), 302 );` / `wp_redirect( home_url('/account/'), 301 );` etc etc

Answer (score 1):

You are establishing a redirect for all requests for a visitor, including `/account`:

- Request to `/`, user is not logged in - redirect to `/account`.
- Request to `/account`, user is not logged in - redirect to `/account`.
- Request to `/account`, user is not logged in - redirect to `/account`.
- (etc.)

To break the loop, perform the redirect only if the request is not for your login page:

```php
function redirect_login_page() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page( 'account' ) ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/account/') );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_login_page' );
```